# Chrome XSL Transformation insert script node security bug?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, xslt, webkit

AJAX loaded xml and xsl then transform it to html. The result node is imported to html container. The result has script element with inline javascript code.
After Chrome update inline code won't executed.

For example: 
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script>
    let buttonElement = document.createElement("button");
        buttonElement.textContent = "Press me";
        document.body.appendChild(buttonElement);

    buttonElement.addEventListener("click", event => {
        Promise.all([fetch('/test.xml'), fetch('/test.xsl')]).then(result => {
            Promise.all([result[0].text(), result[1].text()]).then(result => {
                let parser = new DOMParser(),
                    xml = parser.parseFromString(result[0], "application/xml"),
                    xsl = parser.parseFromString(result[1], "application/xml"),
                    target = document.body,
                    processor = new XSLTProcessor(),
                    output;

                processor.importStylesheet(xsl);
                output = processor.transformToDocument(xml);

                let newOutput = document.body.appendChild(output.documentElement);
/* 
Uncomment the block below,  the result node its replacement  helps and inline script will be executed properly 
*/
/*              newOutput.querySelectorAll("script").forEach(element => {
                    let replacement = document.createElement("script");
                    replacement.text = element.text;
                    element.replaceWith(replacement);
                });         
*/
            });
        });
    }, false);
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hello>
    <world/>
</hello>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <div>
            <p>Hello world</p>
            <script>console.log("Test me!");</script>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, is it security bug of Webkit? Because, this bug was also detected in Opera.

And if this is security solution, why inline script is succesfully executed after result node replacement?

Comment: There is a reason the API for XSLT inside the browser has a `transformToFragment` method, if you use that you stand a chance that browsers execute your script, at least in theory: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-scripting.html#interaction-of-script-elements-and-xslt

Comment: Ok, I've the same problem with AJAX requests with out XSLT transformations, all requests on Webkit like browsers, responding html code with inline javascript doesn't execute it after load and pasting node in DOMDocument.

Comment: I'm using such XSL transformations for many years. And it works properly. But a few days ago, when I've updated chrmo browser, the inline script sections has become unexecuted. I've found trick to fix it, by replacing itself after node inserted in DOM.